# How to set "empty cache and hard reload" as the google chrome reload button default?

Tags: google-chrome, settings

I use Google Chrome to test webpages.  Sometimes the reload does not pick up the changes to my code because it’s reading from the cache.  If I hold down the reload button two other options are offered; three total:
1.  Normal Reload (the default)
2.  Hard Reload
3.  Hard Reload and Empty Cache

Numbers 2 and 3 seem to do the trick so how can either one of them be set to be the default when selecting the Reload button?  Currently, I have to hold down the Reload button, wait for the dropdown, and select my choice for each and every test.  (A lot of tests in a day.)

I have Googled this question and checked multiple sites.  Several tell how to use all three of the options and their effect but none offer an option for setting others for the default.

There are similar questions here on stackoverflow but no solution.  They only describe the behavior and effect of each option.

This could help all developers using Google Chrome for web development.